# Is there an option type?

Tags: r, option-type

This language being multi-paradigm, I wonder if there exists an Option type in R (Some/None), natively or in a package.

It would be [similar to F#](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/), or to C# nullables.

So instead of using `NULL`, we would have a type wrapper:

```
square <- function(x) {
  if (class(x) == "numeric")
    return( Some(x*x) )
  else
    return( None )
}

square(2)
> 4
square("foo")
> None
```

Then you could also filter it out:

```
if (square(x) == Some(4))
  print(x)
```

If it doesn't exist, did anyone tried to implement it?

Comment: Did you mean like S3 methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an implementation of such (handy) types in R, so I created mine.

*UPDATE: Now available as a package on [github](https://github.com/antoinechampion/optional) and on the [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optional/index.html).*

---

**Quickstart:**

An optional variable can be set to `some(object)` or to `none`.

```
a <- some(5)
class(a)
## [1] "optional"
```

Operators and print will have the same behavior with an optional than with its base type.

```
a == 5
## [1] TRUE
a
## [1] 5
```

Note that `some(some(obj))` equals `some(obj)` and that `some(none)` equals `FALSE`.

---

To make an existing function accept optionals as arguments and also return an optional, one can use `make_opt()`:

```
c_opt <- make_opt(c)
c_opt(some(2), none, some(5))
## [1] 2 5
c_opt()
## [1] "None"
```

---

*Bonus part:* I also introduced pattern matching from functional languages, with `match_with`:

```
match_with( variable,
pattern , result-function,
...
```

This is meant to be used with `Magrittr` package if you want to get a syntax as close as the functional `match with`:

```
a <- 5
match_with(a,
  . %>% some(.),          print,
  none,                   function() print("Error!")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the [maybe](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/monads/versions/0.0.0.9000/topics/maybe) type within package [monads](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/monads) which I think is more useful.  I had a look at optional in CRAN but it is not a monad which limits its usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

I made a package which implements a maybe type which is equivalent to an option type. https://armcn.github.io/maybe/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).